# How to fire javascript function after scrolling to certain div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I fire this function only at the time when I scroll down to "myTargetElement" and it becomes visible on the screen, and not immediately after page is loaded?

```
<script src="countUp.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var countOptions = {
        useEasing : true,
        useGrouping : true,
        separator : ',',
        decimal : '.'
    }
    var customerNumber = new countUp("myTargetElement", 0, 1635, 0, 7, countOptions);
    customerNumber.start();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing much yet, just started to learn this language;)

Answer (score 0):

On scroll event check whether target element offset top and document scroll top is same, if same then trigger function

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($('.myTargetElement').offset().top == $(document).scrollTop()){
        //Trigger function
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script fires it as soon as it gets visible (http://jsfiddle.net/f1xbgy86/1/):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                 if(isElementVisible($('#yourElementID'))) {
        $(window).off('scroll');
                     //Call From here

}
});


function isElementVisible(elem)
{
    var visibleTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var visibleBottom = visibleTop + $(window).height();

    return ((elem.offset().top + elem.height()) <= visibleBottom);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's almost what I needed:) how do I fire it only once?

Comment: Just use $(window).off('scroll'); . Look at the updated answer.